# Parse plist file in Python

Tags: python, plist

I have an issue with my Python code. I have a plist file.

**Info.plist**

```
<plist>
  <dict>
    <key>Apple Car Version</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>Last Backup Date</key>
    <date/>
    <key>Product Type</key>
    <string>iPad2,5</string>
    <key>Product Version</key>
    <string>9.3.1</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

**My Python Code**:

```
import os
import plistlib

def main():

   fileName=os.path.expanduser('Info.plist')

   if os.path.exists(fileName):

      pl=plistlib.readPlist(fileName)

      if 'Product Version' in pl:
         print( 'The aString value is %s\n' % pl['Apple Car Version'])

      else:
         print( 'There is no Apple Car Version in the plist\n')

   else:
      print( '%s does not exist, so can\'t be read' % fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Ok so I wrote out some code, but I'm facing BIGGER problems now, I found out it wasn't my code but my plist The Last Backup Date in the plist cause errors. Is there a way where I can only parsh the strings, nothing else like `<date/>`

By the way this plist was made by iTunes if your wondering

Answer (score 2):

That plist file isn't well formed xml at all, so I doubt it will work. I think you need (at a minimum) a root plist element and a dict wrapper:

```
<plist>
  <dict>
    <key>Apple Car Version</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then the keys of `pl` will be the keys you actually define in your file, so "Apple Car Version" in this case:

```
print(pl['Apple Car Version'])
```

Comment: Also see plist(5) https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/plist.5.html for more details on the plist file format

Comment: OK I updated my answer, I'm getting syntax error: NameError: name 'load' is not defined , Do I need to import an other module?

Comment: Ok so I wrote out some code, but I'm facing BIGGER problems now, I found out it wasn't my code but my plist The Last Backup Date in the plist cause errors. Is there a way where I can only parsh the string nothing else like <date/>

Comment: I don't think an empty date is valid in a plist...I think the convention is to omit the key entirely if its value is null. In any case, plistlib doesn't support it, and as you saw will attempt to parse the entire file and fail if there is an empty date. If you need to pluck parts out of the file, and are willing to give up compatibility with the binary plist format, you could use any of the python xml parsers to get what you need directly out of the xml. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html]